# Dell Precision upgraded to xubuntu 20.04 and now shuts down

Tags: upgrade, xubuntu, dell, shutdown

I have been using a dell precision workstation with xubuntu for a while.  I upgraded lts release to 20.04 and now it the display is dark within minutes of the startup.
The dell diagnostics are flagging the hard drive controller as missing.
The fans and other components were OK from the diagnostics.

Does anyone have suggestions for getting the system working again?

Thanks,
Glenn

Answer (score 0):

I checked the graphics card and the fan was not working and the card was hot. Switching graphics cards appears to fix the issue.